# Losing VB.NET "My.Settings" with each new ClickOnce deployment release

Tags: vb.net, winforms, clickonce, settings

I am using the built-in My.Settings functionality in VB.NET to save application settings.

This is very convenient but I notice that each time I release a new version, the settings are lost.

Why and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Trying to clarify.  You are using the built-in settings on the Settings tab of your project's property page.  What is the "Scope" value for your settings - "Application" or "User"?

Comment: hmmm. I assumed (and still suspect) that the settings are at the user scope. How can I tell?

Comment: I found it. Yes, it is at the User scope.

Answer (score 9):

You need to manually update your application settings, I use this easy method:

- Create a boolean setting called MustUpgrade, User scope, default to True.

Then write a method to check if My.Settings requires updating, and call it's Update() method if so. Flag your settings as updated, and save. Call this somewhere in your app load. The Upgrade() method will update your Settings to the new format, and migrate your existing values over.

```
Sub UpgradeMySetings()
    If My.Settings.MustUpgrade Then
        My.Settings.Upgrade()
        My.Settings.MustUpgrade = False
        My.Settings.Save()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Interesting...How do you set a default value for a Property Setting? The Settings tab of the App Properties dialog doesn't seem to support it. I am wondering if it would be harmful to u[grade unconditionally...

Comment: In your project properties, the Settings tab shows a grid where you can define your application settings. Last column (value) is the default value. Enter "True" into this cell. Same for 2005 and 2008, more info at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25zf0ze8.aspx

Comment: Unconditional upgrades will work, the test is just good practice, and for those cases where you need to pre-process old settings before migrating them to the new ones. So the logic is there *in case* a future version needs it ;)

Comment: I take it back. It didn't work. I have the same issue as posted here:
http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/854235-my-settings-upgrade-doesnt-upgrade
I am using click-Once to deploy the Winfform app. I suspect that each upgrade goes to a new folder. I am signing the app with a temporary signature file. This did not solve my issue as it did for the poster.

Comment: Hmm. My Deployment program is signed, but the actual app is not. I can't sign the app because not all of the binary  components I used are signed.

Comment: Remember that each instance (bin\debug, bin\release, clickonce install) keeps it's own copy of settings. Also when you recreate your signature, the app is considered a 'different app', and settings won't migrate. Once you sign, keep that key (note they expire each year.)

Comment: That's why I left ClickOnce, and many other issues it gave. I use a self extractor, and the upgrade function always works great in our production apps.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me after I got rid of a little problem -- it raised a COMException (0x8007001f) when upgrading the settings in the constructor of my custom application context: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9970949/81231