Retrieving/preserving My.Settings values when installing new program version
I have a Visual Basic .NET Windows Forms Application (.NET Framework) that uses a number of values stored in My.Settings, all stored as 'Scope=User'. I install it with Inno Setup. Currently, when I install a new version of the program, the values are reset to their default values.
Q1/ Is there a way that the install of a new version of the program would not change the existing My.Settings values?
Q2/ If 'no' to Q1, then is there a way that I could retrieve the existing values stored in My.Settings, and then apply them to a new install of the program?
Q3/ What should be my future approach to this issue be? Perhaps an '.ini file' rather than using My.Settings?
I am using the same AppId value in my Inno Setup file all of the time.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1708001/14171304 + ApplicationSettingsBase.Upgrade.
